# Tengo problemas tipeando caracteres especiales en VS Code

Tags: vscode

VS Code no me deja escribir los caracteres especiales en sus teclas correspondientes. No sé si se voló algo en la configuración o qué pasó.
Escribe los caracteres, pero no en sus teclas correspondientes ¿Alguna recomendación?

PD: Eso solo me pasa con VS Code, el paquete de idioma y del teclado no son el problema, está en Español internacional

Comment: Cuantas idiomas tienes instalados en tu ordenador

Comment: Tú pregunta no tiene relación con temas de programación.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente sea una extensión. En mi caso el problema era el Notepadd++.

Saludos,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]